# Add CSS Style to Wordpress Sidebar on Article Page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to add a unique CSS style to the articles and single pages sidebar on my site to diferenciate from the home page. The sidebar already has a style called ".sidebar" and it works when I change it, but it affects all the site sidebars.

I've been looking at the sidebars.php file and see there are "if" lines for home or single pages, but don't know what to change. Keep in mind I'm not a programmer.

The code I think should be modified is (sidebar.php):

```
<aside class="sidebar">
<?php
    wp_reset_query();
    if ( is_home() ){

        $sidebar_home = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_home' );
        if( $sidebar_home )
            dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_home ) ); 

        else dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );  

    }elseif( is_page() ){
        global $get_meta;
        $tie_sidebar_pos = $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0];

        if( $tie_sidebar_pos != 'full' ){
            $tie_sidebar_post = sanitize_title($get_meta["tie_sidebar_post"][0]);
            $sidebar_page = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_page' );
            if( $tie_sidebar_post )
                dynamic_sidebar($tie_sidebar_post);

            elseif( $sidebar_page )
                dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_page ) ); 

            else dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );
        }

    }elseif ( is_single() ){
        global $get_meta;
        $tie_sidebar_pos = $get_meta["tie_sidebar_pos"][0];

        if( $tie_sidebar_pos != 'full' ){
            $tie_sidebar_post = sanitize_title($get_meta["tie_sidebar_post"][0]);
            $sidebar_post = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_post' );
            if( $tie_sidebar_post )
                dynamic_sidebar($tie_sidebar_post);

            elseif( $sidebar_post )
                dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_post ) ); 

            else dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );
        }

    }elseif ( is_category() ){

        $category_id = get_query_var('cat') ;
        $cat_sidebar = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_cat_'.$category_id ) ;
        $sidebar_archive = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_archive' );

        if( $cat_sidebar )
            dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $cat_sidebar ) ); 

        elseif( $sidebar_archive )
            dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_archive ) );

        else dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );

    }else{
        $sidebar_archive = tie_get_option( 'sidebar_archive' );
        if( $sidebar_archive ){
            dynamic_sidebar ( sanitize_title( $sidebar_archive ) );
        }
        else dynamic_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );
    }
?>
</aside>
```

Thanks in advance for any help solving this.

Comment: articles  is a page.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your article should have a unique page or post id, have a look at the page/post source code to get the id. Your css will look something like `#post_455 .sidebar {
/* your unique article styles */
}`

ps - you shouldn't need to play around with sidebar.php

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer. I've tried your sugestion and it didn't worked. Besides if it do it will be too tedious to create a style for each article id. I found that the generated html looks like:
<body id="top" class="single single-post postid-1443">
 <div class="wrapper full-site layout-2c">
  <div class="top-nav head_menu">
   <div class="container">
    <header>
     <div id="main-content" class="container">
      <div class="content-wrap">
       <aside class="sidebar">
        <div class="search-widget">
        </div>
       </aside>

Comment: Is it possible to add a style like: .single-post .sidebar {CSS} Because I've also tried that and didn't worked.

Comment: Sorry, I read through your question again. Add a unique style to the home page if that is the only page you want to look different. The home page will have a unique id or class.

Comment: Great Nick. I noticed that each type of page had it's own ID, so I did something like this: body.single-post .sidebar {margin-top: 250px !important;} and it worked great. Thanks a lot for pointing to the right direction.